# Chrome App - Webview Proxy support [PC]

Tags: webview, proxy, google-chrome-app

I am loading external websites inside google chrome app using webview, I want to load those URLs through some proxy IP instead of my local IP. I checked webview tag but couldn't find any options for proxy.Is there a way to achieve this.

window.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Hello, world!</div>
    <webview id="wv1" partition="p1" style="width: 450px; height: 300px; border: 2px solid red" src="http://www.google.com"></webview>
    <webview id="wv2" partition="p2" style="width: 450px; height: 300px; border: 2px solid red" src="http://www.nytimes.com"></webview>
    <webview id="wv3" partition="p3" style="width: 450px; height: 300px; border: 2px solid red" src="http://www.stackoverflow.com"></webview>
    <webview id="wv4" partition="p4" style="width: 450px; height: 300px; border: 2px solid red" src="http://www.yahoo.com"></webview>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to affect that from an app.

Presumably, a Chrome App inherits proxy settings from the browser, and `<webview>` has no way to affect this. Extensions [have an API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/proxy) to manipulate that setting, but [Apps do not](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_index).